# Issue inflating with TableLayout

Tags: android

I have created a view in `XML`. In Android Studio it is looking like

[image]

But when I am running it on my device it is not inflating properly. It is missing rows!!

[image]

`XML` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
    
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view3"
            android:layout_width="0.6dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/colorDisabledLight"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/table"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvAvoidDummy"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/table" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAvoidDummy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_no_drugs_1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_no_drugs_1"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_half_margin"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="Miss Dose"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:shrinkColumns="1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/rowAvoid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAvoid"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_no_drugs_1"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_no_drugs_1"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_half_margin"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="Avoid"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccentDark" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAvoidSummary"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="Should be avoided in hypertensive patients and during pregnancy"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp" />
    
            </TableRow>
    
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.7dp"
                android:background="@color/colorDisabledLight" />
    
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/rowFood"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFood"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_cocktail"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_cocktail"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_half_margin"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="Food"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccentDark" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFoodSummary"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="Avoid Alcohol"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp" />
    
            </TableRow>
    
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.7dp"
                android:background="@color/colorDisabledLight" />
    
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/rowStorage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvStorage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_downloading_drawer"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_downloading_drawer"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_half_margin"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="Storage"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccentDark" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvStorageSummary"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="Store in a cool and dry place"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp" />
    
            </TableRow>
    
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.7dp"
                android:background="@color/colorDisabledLight" />
    
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/rowMissDose"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMissDose"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_drugs"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_drugs"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_half_margin"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="Miss Dose"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccentDark" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMissDoseSummary"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:text="Skip the missed dose and continue your regular dosing schedule. Do not take two doses at the same time."
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp" />
    
            </TableRow>
    
        </TableLayout>
    
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I cannot figure it out what is wrong with the code because of which the view is not inflating properly at runtime.
I am not changing the visibility of any `TableRow` in the code but still, it is missing the rows and it is different for different devices.

Comment: `android:id="@+id/tvAvoidDummy"` is just a dummy text. I don't want to show it either.

Comment: Could you try adding `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rowStorage"` in the not shown table?